# React — passing (this) onClick?

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I'm trying to pass this from an inline onClick to a function and I know I'm making a stupid mistake... but my brain is a bit melted.

Here is a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/69z2wepo/48261/).

```
handleClick() {
  $('.nav-link').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: maybe you should not use jquery to do this, better use component state to store information about active item, and use it in you render: https://jsfiddle.net/euo2p1h2/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many possible solutions (one of them is using ref's). But I edited your fiddle with a simpler approach:

```
  handleClick(e) {
    $('.nav-link').removeClass('active');
    $(e.target).addClass('active');
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/esn5sz5b/2/

Anyway, I suggest another approach instead of jquery. You can manually handle active items with some logic using react.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something tiny :)